# blackfire config issue with php probe

Tags: php, blackfire

**So I'm trying to install "Blackfire" from Sensiolab and following all the instructions et.. I'm facing an issue when lauching it to profile my app and also for any related php cli that I'm running...:**

**The error message is:**
“Unable to load dynamic library ‘/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/blackfire.so’” => faire enough, there is no blackfire.so in that directory...

**The I checked my blackfire.ini and the config seems fien referencing the path where blackfire.so is actually stored:**
[blackfire]
extension="/usr/local/Cellar/blackfire-php71-zts/1.23.1/blackfire.so"

**I also tried to add some config to php.ini and when I run phpinfo() nothing has been updated...:**

[blackfire]
extension=blackfire.so
; On Windows use the following configuration:
; extension=php_blackfire.dll

; Sets the socket where the agent is listening.
; Possible value can be a unix socket or a TCP address.
; Defaults to unix:///var/run/blackfire/agent.sock on Linux,

; unix:///usr/local/var/run/blackfire-agent.sock ;on MacOSX,

; and to tcp://127.0.0.1:8307 on Windows.
;blackfire.agent_socket = unix:///var/run/blackfire/agent.sock

blackfire.agent_timeout = 0.25

Thanks in advance for your help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually I resolved the issue by:

- Getting rid of MAMP stack as the php version installed with Homebrew  was conflicting with the MAMP version and I honesty couldn't figure out which php.ini was used eventually even using the related command... it was showing the homerew one but I had the feeling that this was causing me issues...
- I uninstalled balckfire and installed it again (no more MAMP)  and of course PHP with Homebrew and it worked fine... just a little set up issue that I had fixed doing the below

changing the default setting in the blackfire.ini

this was defaulted ***socket=tcp://127.0.0.1:8307*** while I have a unix/OSx and the following should have been defaulted instead ***unix:///usr/local/var/run/blackfire-agent.sock***

Hope this will help someone in the same situation